# Can't disabled Wordpress autop Filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site running on WP5.5.3 (newest) with the Classic Editor installed.
Now I have a shortcode, that adds some basic html code but WP does destroy it by adding a bunch of `<p>` and `<br>` tags into it.

I tried adding this directly into my functions.php

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

I also tried looking up the priority of wpautop on the_content in the `global $wp_filter` object and removed it accordingly on priority 99 and 10, but also to no effect.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1st, try to disable both, as shown in [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop):

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

2nd, clear all cache (plugins, server if any, browser). I have it disabled like this, so it should work for you as well...

Comment: Tried this with all plugins disabled, searched through all themes for anything that accesses the wpautop. Nothing helped so far. I am kind of baffeled as to why this isn't working. It has worked on other projects, but not this one. I think the issue might be too specific to get help here

Comment: you have any kind of server cache enabled?

Comment: Nope, I am checking the files on the server, debugging with die; statements. Ported the whole page to a local dev server. All the same result

Comment: All caches cleared. This solution is the official WP one, and it *DOESN'T WORK AT ALL*.